# Php multi dimensional array check other array for sorting while using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an two array like this below

**First:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Basic
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 1
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => House rent allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 2
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Conveyance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 3
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Car allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 4
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Cost of living allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 5
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Food allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 6
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => Telephone allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 7
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => Special allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 8
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => Vehicle allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 9
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => Other allowance fixed
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 10
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => Oman pasi
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 13
        [earning_or_deduction] => 2
    )

[81] => Array
    (
        [name] => Salary advance payment
        [parameter_type] => 2
        [id] => 18
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
    )

)
```

**Second:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Basic
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 1
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 12999.999
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => House rent allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 2
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 1500
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Conveyance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 3
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 750
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Car allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 4
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 750
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Cost of living allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 5
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 750
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Food allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 6
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 750
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => Telephone allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 7
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 150
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => Special allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 8
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 200.001
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => Vehicle allowance
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 9
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 249.999
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => Other allowance fixed
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 10
        [earning_or_deduction] => 1
        [per_day_amount] => 350.001
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => Oman pasi
        [parameter_type] => 1
        [id] => 13
        [earning_or_deduction] => 2
        [per_day_amount] => 210
    )

)
```

While doing for each i have to check based on id , if id not available on 2nd array means need to place empty array like below

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [name] => ''
        [parameter_type] => 0
        [id] =>0
        [earning_or_deduction] =>0
        [per_day_amount] =>0
    )
```

I tried using array merge with duplicate removal but no luck because i need to check while doing foreach.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear from the question

Answer (score 2):

```
$ids = array_column($array2, 'id');
foreach($array1 as $a) {
    if (!array_search($a['id'], $ids)) {
        //Add empty array
    }
    else {
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Will sure update the answer with required explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$FinalData = [];
foreach ($FirstArray as $FirstArr) {
    $FinalData[] = Get_Amount($FirstArr['id'], $SecondArray);
}

function Get_Amount($id, $Arrays)
{
    $Amount = '';
    // Arrays is Your Second Array
    foreach ($Arrays as $Array) {
        if ($Array['id'] == $id) {
            $MyArray = $Array;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (empty($Amount)) {
        return [
            'name' => '',
            'parameter_type' => 0,
            'id' => 0,
            'earning_or_deduction' => 0,
            'per_day_amount' => 0
        ];
    }
    return $Array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with,

```
    $id_dic = array_column($array2,null,"id");
    foreach($array1 as &$v){
        if(!isset($id_dic[$v["id"]])){
            $v = array(
                'name' => '',
                'parameter_type' => 0,
                'id' =>0,
                'earning_or_deduction' =>0,
                'per_day_amount' =>0
            );
        }
    }
```